# Euler characteristic of a compact surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Determine the Euler characteristic of the surface

$$ M=\left\{(x,y,z); \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1+z^{2n}, 0< z< 1\right\} $$

Comment: For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (including n=0), you just have one cylinder. For non-positive integers, the disjoint union of two cylinders.

Comment: Sounds like homework...

Comment: This doesn't look compact to me...

Answer (score 4):

For any $n\in \mathbb{R}$, your surface is a cylinder, and homotopic to the circle.

(I don't see why Agusti Roig gets the disjoint union of two cylinders)